# React Native Android Emoji Compat

Tags: android, react-native, emoji

may i know how to implement this https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/preview/emoji-compat.html to be useful for React Native development? I want to display latest emojis in my React Native Android app..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems https://github.com/twitter/twemoji or https://github.com/moqada/rn-twemoji could be a possible approach for unifying the support of emoji across all the android devices

Comment: Thanks mate! @PETEroid

Answer (score 2):

I have made a request on [React-native](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/adding-emojicompat-to-react-native) and [Expo](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/adding-emojicompat-to-expo) canny if you like this to be added to react native vote it up. Sorry, I didn't have enough reps to make this post as a comment that's why I have added it as an answer.

**twoemoji** is not an answer to your question. Your android device should be able to understand the Unicode code, which in the case of older android phones, some of those Unicodes (specially flags) are not translatable or mappable to the emoji image.

**Unifying** and **being able to map to the right emoji image** are two separate issues!

Unifying means both iOS and android show the same image, but that doesn't solve the problem of the older android models understanding the new Unicode and mapping it to the right image character.

The last but not the least, I don't recommend to manually map the Unicode to the emoji assets, since it is going to add up to the size of your bundled app.